# How can I make the indicator overlays the tab and not the opposite

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Guys who understand reactnative and know how to use reactnavigation.

I'm creating a open-source application and im using on it a MaterialTopTabNavigator. When i stylize the tab and the indicator (using indicatorStyle and tabStyle), the tab overlays the indicator, make it invisible. Someone know how to fix it? I want to make the indicator overlays the tab, and not the opposite

GitHub repository: https://www.github.com/arthrc/packly
src/route.js line 30~49

```js
export default function Routes() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator 
        initialRouteName='Home'
        tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: '#fff',
            inactiveTintColor: '#f7f7f7',
            tabStyle: { backgroundColor: '#a500ff'},
            indicatorStyle: {
                height: 6,
                bottom: -3,
                backgroundColor: '#D70CE8',
                width:100,
            },
            labelStyle: {
                fontFamily: 'Inter_600SemiBold',
                fontSize: 16
            }
        }}
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the `tabStyle` to `style` and it worked perfectly

final code:

```js
export default function Routes() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator 
        initialRouteName='Home'
        tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: '#fff',
            inactiveTintColor: '#f7f7f7',
            tabStyle: { backgroundColor: '#a500ff'},
            indicatorStyle: {
                height: 6,
                bottom: -3,
                backgroundColor: '#D70CE8',
                width:100,
            },
            labelStyle: {
                fontFamily: 'Inter_600SemiBold',
                fontSize: 16
            }
        }}
        >
```